# How to handle relational tables in SQL database?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am developing a jewelry management system using C#, Visual Studio 2022, and MySQL database. Each jewelry item is stored in a separate table with the respective primary keys. I want to change the state of the item from unpurchased to purchase in the receipt generating form. As it changes, they should get deleted from previous tables and get inserted in a new table that contains all purchased items.* **A simple diagram is given.***

I searched for it but couldn't find it.

Comment: “Each jewelry item is stored in a separate table” This sounds like a bad start. It is not common to create a new table for each product type. Instead, create two tables: one describing the jewelry_type and one containing the actual instance with a reference to its type. The whole idea of a relational database is that you want to make the data unique and reference each other. That ultimately the product table is nothing more than a reference to what particular product it is and perhaps something unique to that instance (e.g. a serial code). This way you are able to create queries to view data.

Comment: This is a good read: [Description of the database normalization basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/database-normalization-description)

Comment: Can only second Jerome's comment; "do not store information in a table or column name that should be in a row". Table names and column names are the equivalent of class names and property names in C# - they should be regarded as fixed things that need reconciliation of a new app to change or add to.

Comment: *As it changes, they should get deleted from previous tables and get inserted in a new table that contains all purchased items* - again we don't typically do this, but instead perhaps have a PurchaseDate column in product, or a SalesHistory table that cites the seller and buyer ids, the date, the amount. We run a query to find all items with a null purchasedate, or no records in SalesHistory for a particular product, meaning the item has never been sold. We don't typically hop data around through multiple tables depending on its status as that is again "using table name to store row info"

Comment: @flackoverstow Good comparison of tables and classes. You are not going to create a class "Necklace" and "Ring". You will then be more likely to have a "Jewelry" class describing a necklace or ring. Although you still see things like this when people make games. But in database design, this is not how most do it.